# Losing KDE desktop when switching

Tags: kde, shortcut-keys, virtualdesktop

This is probably something simple but it's quite frustrating.

I have KDE set up to have **two** desktops set under "System Settings->Virtual Desktops". I can type ctrl-left and ctrl-right to switch between them no problem.

If I type "window-tab", however, I appear to switch to another desktop... and I can even do it twice and get to a 3rd desktop. But, I can never get back to my main one. In fact the only way I've ever been able to get back to my primary one is finding an app in the system tray that's on my main desktop, and telling it to focus.

Any idea what might be going on here? I have a feeling I've got two different virtual-desktop schemes running at once, I just don't know what the "windows tab" command is invoking.

Comment: That seems to be it! Not sure why meta-shift-tab didn't get me back before, but now that I'm using 2 monitors instead of one, it seems to magically work. Any reason you answered in a comment instead of an Answer? I'd love to accept your answer as correct.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I understood your problem correctly; just converted my comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably switching activities with that key combination.

Try looking at the global keyboard shortcut management (should come up if you type key in the `alt`+`f2`-dialog), and then choose plasma desktop from the dropdown menu. I have something like "next activity" there, which in my case is mapped on `meta`+`tab`. Getting back should be `meta`+`shift`+`tab`, so just try `windows`+`shift`+`tab` on your keyboard to get back.

If you want to, you can also disable the shortcut from the same menu.